# Calculate the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\sin(2x))}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\sin(2x))}{x}$$

I'm not allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule. I tried to make the substitutions $2x=y$ and $\sin(2x)=y$, but I couldn't get something to use $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ (this is the only one I can use this moment). I tried to use $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ as well, but I didn't get anywhere too. I'm only asking a hint this moment! Thanks!

Comment: Not able or not allowed ?

Comment: allowed. Sorry for my english

Comment: Don't worry, @Dunck.  A lot of native English users confuse the two, as well!

Comment: No problem, but I needed to know. That makes different answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin{x}} = 1$, so

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\sin(2x))}{x}=
2\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\sin(2x))}{\sin(2x)}\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}=2$$

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: Please learn to format trig function: `\tan x`, `\sin x`, `\cos x`, `\cot x,`\sec x`, `\csc x` ...

Comment: @amWhy I just saw your revision and will try to remember, thank you!

Comment: No problem, @Andronicus.  formatting can sometimes be a steep learning curve!